# SHAP plots saving figures as blank/white, but Matplotlib saves figures fine

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, data-science, shap

I am attempting to plot a SHAP summary plot after training a Random Forest. I using VSCode to ssh into a remote worker and run my code there. When I run my code to generate and save the image, it does not throw any error, but only generates a white box/blank plot. This code is below (top). What's unusual is that when I test generating and saving figures with Matplotlib outside of SHAP, but on this ssh tunnel, it works totally fine (bottom).

I am using matplotlib version = 1.5.1 and SHAP version = 0.34.0. It is worth noting a few things about my attempts to debug this and my set up: (1) this exact code worked on a previous worker that I no longer have access to. To me, this suggests that it is a problem with the environment configuration; (2) I tried using `plt.gcf()` to get the SHAP plot into a purely matplotlib object and saving that, but this also did not work; (3) I have tried closing the plot (`plt.close()`) prior to the new `plt.figure()`, but this also did not work; (4) I have tried my current code both with and without the `matplotlib=True` flag; (5) I am trying to generate many SHAP figures (not shown), these also produced blank/white plots; (6) I am using a Mac, the remote worker is Linux (Ubuntu).

Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks.

CURRENT CODE -- RETURNS WHITE BOX/BLANK PLOT

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import numpy as np
import os
import csv
import shap
import pickle
import warnings
import pydot

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve, GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib 

matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fit random forest here. very long, so I decided to omit it

plt.figure()
fig1 = shap.summary_plot(shap_values,tt, show=False, matplotlib=True, plot_type="bar", plot_size=(10, 10))
plt.savefig('/home/path/path/shap_summary.png', dpi=600)
plt.close()
```

MATPLOTLIB OUTSIDE OF SHAP -- SAVES A NORMAL PLOT

```
plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000) 
plt.plot(x, np.log(x))      
plt.savefig('home/path/thisworks.png')
plt.close()
```

Comment: The last line in `shap.summary_plot`  is `pl.show()` (pl for plt), so there is nothing returned from Python interpreter, unless you edit the source code.

Comment: Please check your code, would you really use this argument `show=False`? See this [comments](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/267#issuecomment-423774317)from Lundberg.

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137579/save-shap-summary-plot-as-pdf-svg) 
Using show=False as the last parameter in the plot worked for me as long as inline function is not enabled.